# Alternate css change on two separate click functions

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click, jquery-animate

I'm attempting to affect a css change on a particular element using two click elements, where each click element affects a different css change dependant on the css properties of the element I wish to change.

I am able to apply these changes using an `if else` statement on the first click element however when I add the second click function it fails to work. Both click function work individually however put together only the first works.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong in the linked JSFiddle?

[JSFiddle of what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/v84cfcu0/)

Comment: Better post your code instead of JSFiddle link.

Comment: @GaryVoss: **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/r98c28Lc/)** is what I was able to produce, out of interest, using **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap)**.

Answer (score 1):

you had syntax error.

```
 $('.next').click(function() {
        if($('.a').css('left') == '0px') {
            $(".a").animate({left: "105px", top: "0px", width: "150px", height: "100px"});
        }
        else if ($('.a').css('left') == '105px') {
            $(".a").animate({left: "260px", top: "25px", width: "100px", height: "50px"});
        }  
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
        if($('.a').css('left') == '105px') {
            $(".a").animate({left: "0px", top: "25px", width: "100px", height: "50px"});
    }
    else if ($('.a').css('left') == '260px') {
        $(".a").animate({left: "105px", top: "0px", width: "150px", height: "100px"});
    }  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v84cfcu0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

You had ($); at the end of each of the click events.

It was looking like this:

```
})($);
```

You don't need the `($);` It should look like the following:

```
});
```

Show here the updated code:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    if($('.a').css('left') == '0px') {
        $(".a").animate({left: "105px", top: "0px", width: "150px", height: "100px"});
    }
    else if ($('.a').css('left') == '105px') {
        $(".a").animate({left: "260px", top: "25px", width: "100px", height: "50px"});
    }  
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    if($('.a').css('left') == '105px') {
        $(".a").animate({left: "0px", top: "25px", width: "100px", height: "50px"});
    }
    else if ($('.a').css('left') == '260px') {
        $(".a").animate({left: "105px", top: "0px", width: "150px", height: "100px"});
    }  
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE FIX**](http://jsfiddle.net/v84cfcu0/3/)